# How do I use this nested array-json response from the API call in my HTML Angular 11

Tags: arrays, json, angular, typescript, api

I get the response from the API calls without any problems, but iterating through the response to get the values always gives errors.

**league.service.ts**

```js
import { Inject, Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { HttpClient, HttpEvent, HttpHandler, HttpHeaders, HttpInterceptor, HttpParams, HttpRequest } from '@angular/common/http';
import { environment } from '../../environments/environment.prod';
import { Observable } from "rxjs";
import { Standing } from "../model/standings.model";
import { Fixture } from '../model/fixtures.model';
import { TopScorer, League } from '../model/topscorers.model';

const enum endpoint {
    standings = '/standings',
    fixtures = '/fixtures',
    top_scorers = '/players/topscorers'
}

@Injectable()
export class LeagueService {
    
    private URL = 'https://v3.football.api-sports.io';
    private API_KEY = environment.api;
    // private league: string;
    // private season: string;

    private headers = new HttpHeaders({
        'x-rapidapi-key': this.API_KEY
    });
    httpParams: HttpParams | { [param: string]: string | string[]; } | undefined;

    // private httpParams = new HttpParams({
    //   fromObject: {
    //     league: '39',
    //     season: '2020'
    //   }
    // })

    constructor( private http: HttpClient ) {}

    getLeagueStandings(httpParams: HttpParams): Observable<Standing> {
        return this.http.get<Standing>(`${this.URL}${endpoint.standings}`, {
            headers: this.headers,
            params: httpParams
        });
    }
}
```

**premier-league.component.ts**

```js
import { HttpClient, HttpParams } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs';
import { Standing } from '../../model/standings.model';
import { LeagueService } from '../../service/league.service';
import { Fixture } from '../../model/fixtures.model';
import { TopScorer } from '../../model/topscorers.model';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-premier-league',
    templateUrl: './premier-league.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./premier-league.component.scss']
})
export class PremierLeagueComponent implements OnInit {
    
    subs: Subscription[] = [];
    standings!: Standing;
    fixtures!: Fixture;
    topScorers!: TopScorer;


    private httpParams = new HttpParams({
        fromObject: {
            league: '39',
            season: '2020'
        }
    })
    
    
    constructor(private http: HttpClient,
                private leagueStanding: LeagueService,
                private leagueTopScore: LeagueService,
                private leagueFixture: LeagueService) { }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.legStanding();
        // this.legFixture();
        // this.topScore();
    }

    
    // tslint:disable-next-line: typedef
    // private legFixture() {
    //   this.leagueStanding.getLeagueFixtures(this.httpParams)
    //     .subscribe(data => this.fixtures = data);
    // }

    // tslint:disable-next-line: typedef
    private legStanding() {
        // tslint:disable-next-line: max-line-length
        this.subs.push(this.leagueStanding.getLeagueStandings(this.httpParams).subscribe(data => console.log(this.standings = data)));
    }
}
```

**standing.model.ts**

```js
export interface Standing {
    get: string;
    parameters: Parameters;
    errors?: (null)[] | null;
    results: number;
    paging: Paging;
    response?: (ResponseEntity)[] | null;
}
export interface Parameters {
    league: string;
    season: string;
}
export interface Paging {
    current: number;
    total: number;
}
export interface ResponseEntity {
    league: League;
}
export interface League {
    id: number;
    name: string;
    country: string;
    logo: string;
    flag: string;
    season: number;
    standings?: ((StandingsEntityEntity)[] | null)[] | null;
}
export interface StandingsEntityEntity {
    rank: number;
    team: Team;
    points: number;
    goalsDiff: number;
    group: string;
    form: string;
    status: string;
    description?: string | null;
    all: AllOrHomeOrAway;
    home: AllOrHomeOrAway;
    away: AllOrHomeOrAway;
    update: string;
}
export interface Team {
    id: number;
    name: string;
    logo: string;
}
export interface AllOrHomeOrAway {
    played: number;
    win: number;
    draw: number;
    lose: number;
    goals: Goals;
}
export interface Goals {
    for: number;
    against: number;
}
```

When I'm trying to use any data from the response, I get these types of errors:

> Type 'ResponseEntity' is not assignable to type 'any[] & Iterable'.

> Type 'ResponseEntity' is not assignable to type 'any[]'.

> Property 'team' does not exist on type 'ResponseEntity'

**console response**

[image: console response from the API call]

Comment: could you also add `premier-league.component.html` code? especially piece of  template with `*ngFor` in it.

Comment: @Andrei 
<div *ngFor="let item of standings.response">
  <div *ngFor="let t of item">
    <div *ngFor="let team of t.league.standings">
      {{ team.team.name }}
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

Comment: <div *ngFor="let t of item> error is here. I believe you just don't need this div. without it the error should be gone

Comment: @Andrei     
    Error occurs in the template of component PremierLeagueComponent.
src/app/components/premier-league/premier-league.component.html:16:13 - error TS2339: Property 'team' does not exist on type 'StandingsEntityEntity[]'.

16     {{ team.team.name }}
               ~~~~

  src/app/components/premier-league/premier-league.component.ts:11:16
    11   templateUrl: './premier-league.component.html',
                      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    Error occurs in the template of component PremierLeagueComponent.